# Does Yasuo's Last breath count as Airborne CC?

Tags: league-of-legends

When playing One for All as a team of Yasuos, our team suddenly noticed something quite nasty. We had to play against a team of Gangplanks and whenever one of us ulted Gangplank, he just walked out of the ultimate after eating some oranges and the rest of us could no longer ult him.

Scurvy cannot remove airborne CC but it can remove stuns. To me, it seems Yasuo's Last Breath does not count as airborne CC as GP can just walk out of it after eating oranges. He just cancels the ultimate and puts himself back on the ground.

But then again, how can other Yasuos still ult a target that is already ulted if it's not airborne CC?

Comment: One for all is back?! I havent been on for a few days, but if this is true I will be quite happy :)

Comment: @nickson104 It will probably last another week or two till sunday. It's going on for a weak now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yasuo's tornado is a knock-up, which can't be removed by Gangplank oranges, where as Yasuo's ultimate is a suspension ( similar to nami's bubble), which can be removed.

That's it.
Source :
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Suspension#Suspension
http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Yasuo

Comment: I didn't even know about that kind of CC. Thought Nami's bubble was a fancier knockup. But would that mean Suspension actually overrides and removes other airborne CC? So Yasou's ult can cancel knockup/back effects.

Comment: @Gnarly404 Well, it does. Ali can headbut someone which gives yasuo the ability to ult and if he does, the target stays where it is.